# Java Regex: Optional Matching

Tags: java, regex

I've been using the following Regex to extract a zip code from a bunch of text:

```
    "\\d{5}\\-?[1-9]?[1-9]?[1-9]?[1-9]?"
```

My intention of making the last 4 [1-9] optional (using ? ) was to be able to extract both 5 digit zip codes and 5 digit zip codes with + 4 such as 11001-1010.

However, it only matches the first two digits of the last four numbers even though I put 4 digits at the end.

For example, in the zip code 11001-1010 it would match 11001-10.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Why not simply make a group? `"\\d{5}(?:\\-\\d{4})?"`.

Comment: For zip code `11001-1010` your regex would only match `11001-1` because the optional 4 digits after the `-` cannot be `0`.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful: the regex engine is *greedy* by default. It tries to match as much as it can (there are no lazy quantifiers in this case). Also, `x{0,4}` is *exactly* the same as `x?x?x?x?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to question: For zip code `11001-1010` your regex would only match `11001-1` because the optional 4 digits after the `-` cannot be `0`.

For the unstated question of how to fix that, it depends on whether you only want to match an optional +4, or you want to also match +3, +2, +1, and +0, like your expression would.

Matching Zip5 with optional +4, e.g. matching `11001-1010` and `11001`:

```
"\\d{5}(?:-\\d{4})?"
```

Matching Zip5 with optional +N, e.g. matching `11001-1010`, `11001-101`, `11001-10`, `11001-1`, `11001-`, and `11001`:

```
"\\d{5}(?:-\\d{0,4})?"
```

**Update**

Now, if you want to make sure it doesn't match the `56789-1234` of `123456789-123456789` or `abcd56789-1234qwerty`, you can add a word-boundary check:

```
"\\b\\d{5}(?:-\\d{4})?\\b"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\\d{5}\\-\\d{0,4}` which allows you to match `0` to `4` digits after `-`.

**EDIT**

> From the comment : But then the - won’t be optional.

For that you can use `\\d{5}(\\-\\d{0,4})?` to make group of `-` and digits after dash optional.

Comment: But then the `-` won’t be optional.

Answer (score 1):

It's stopping at the first 0 in the suffix, 
    "\d{5}\-?[1-9]?[1-9]?[1-9]?[1-9]?"
So in your example, it only matches up to 11001-1
Does "\d{5}\-?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?" work ok?
The other answers are probably cleaner, but that is the bug.

Looks ok per [this](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRiq1bAYDA/index.html)